# варианты meta description

Tags: html, meta

Какие варианты **description** допускаются в мета теге? Т.е. какие варианты поисковики отрабатывают и понимают правильно? Есть такие:

1. `<meta itemprop="description" content="rugby exchange nz es una empresa neocelandeza especializada en programas de alto rendimiento de rugby y representante exclusivo de la auckland rugby academy">`;
2. `<meta http-equiv="description" content="uae business review" />`;
3. `<meta name="description" content="full movie stream and tv series online free stream in hd and 1080p on openload. watch movies in theaters online , free cinema movie stream and download" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце, `meta itemprop="description"` описывает страницу для микроразметки (зачем и как, [читай здесь](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/schema-org/)) остальные два:

Мета теги типа NAME содержат текстовую информацию о документе, его авторе и некоторые рекомендации для поисковых машин. Например: Robots, Description, Keywords, Author, Copyright.

Мета теги типа HTTP-EQUIV влияют на формирование заголовка документа и определяют режим его обработки.

Подробнее написано в [этой статье](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/vse-o-meta-tegah.html).

Comment: получается ```<meta itemprop="description"``` == ```<meta name="description"``` в плане описания страницы, я верно понимаю? Второй вариант является не верным, значит и поисковики его верно не идентифицируют, правильно?

Comment: @Василий скажу лишь что в своей практике я использовал лишь `<meta itemprop="description" == <meta name="description"` и да, это описание страницы, просто 1-е описание определенного стандарта где вы описываете сущность, и говорите что это страницы и она имеет описание, и так далее, это скажем так расширенный набор параметров или атрибутов/свойств, как удобней, самыми популярными являются schema.org и open graph, которые позволяют по мимо описания страницы выделить и другие сущности на ней, в частности это позволяет собирать некий каталог с сайта с ценами и прочее, а не просто описание страницы

Comment: og теги вроде только для отображения в соцсетях в отличии от schema?

Comment: @Василий именно, og и schema.org отличаются друг от друга